# Please help explain initialization syntax c++

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, parentheses

```
#include "../data-structures/RMQ.h"

struct LCA {
    int T = 0;
    vi time, path, ret;
    RMQ<int> rmq;

    LCA(vector<vi>& C) : time(sz(C)), rmq((dfs(C,0,-1), ret)) {}
    void dfs(vector<vi>& C, int v, int par) {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
};
```

In this line `rmq((dfs(C,0,-1), ret))`, I don't understand how `(dfs(C,0,-1), ret)` forms a valid input argument (i.e. a `vector<int>`) for the RMQ constructor. What do the surrounding parentheses do and how are the `dfs()` and `ret` used?

Comment: someone is trying to be clever, `rmq((dfs(C,0,-1), ret))` is actually `dfs(C,0,-1); rmq(ret)`, without a [mre]  it's difficult to say why the author decided to write "clever" rather than understandable code

Answer (score 2):

That's a tricky piece of code. The author is using the dreaded [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) to first call `dfs(...)` and then initialize the `rmq` vector with the value of `ret`.

In short, `(dfs(C,0,-1), ret)` first calls `dfs`, discards its result, and then evaluates to `ret`.

Don't write code like this if you can avoid it, it's confusing.

Comment: It might be worth adding that ,in this specific example, the validity of the code is reliant on the order of the members of the class, which is extremely fragile at best.